# Make random JTextField Yellow

Tags: java, arrays, random, jtextfield, setbackground

I have 9 textfields in my design that are named box1,box2 etc. I want to make one of these yellow. So i did put the names of the textfields in an array and tried to use the Random function to pick one of these names. But it doesnt work.

```
String[] boxes = new String[]{"box1", "box2", "box3", "box4", "box5", "box6", 
    "box7", "box8", "box9"};

Random rand = new Random();
int randomint = rand.nextInt(9);
String thatBox = boxes[randomint];

thatBox.setBackground(Color.yellow);
```

Comment: Uh, where's the JTextField?

Comment: Im sorry for the poor explanation. I have 9 textfields in my design that are named box1,box2 etc. I want to make one of these yellow.

Comment: Ok, so did the other guy answer your question? Cuz I am still confused

Comment: Well, it looks like the answer but it doesnt compile so no.

Comment: `String`s do not have a `setBackground()` property, I suggest you go study

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `String[]` boxes to `JTextField[]` and have each element the actual `JTextField`

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class SOQ10
{
   public void something()
   {
      String[] box = new String[]{"box1", "box2", "box3", "box4", "box5", "box6", 
         "box7", "box8", "box9"};

      JTextField[] boxes = new JTextField[9];

      for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
      {
         boxes[i] = new JTextField(box[i]);          
      }

      Random rand = new Random();
      int randomint = rand.nextInt(9);
      boxes[randomint].setBackground(Color.yellow);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what the OP is trying to do? I'm just confused cuz he mentioned JTextFields, but all I was strings